# Virtual Machine compatibility

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, nvme

when choosing the host machine hardware for very old virtual machines, how much additional risk is there when using modern hardware?

I have a Windows XP virtual machine VHD Gen 1 with a program that I must continue to use year after year, I am currently hosting it on a boring old 2010s era PC, and it works reliably well. I am interested to buy a new PC Win11, NVMe, and migrate the VHD image there. I am experienced in virtual machine management, I am not asking for basic instructions. If I use a very old VHD Gen 1 WinXPx32 on Hyper-V (or VMware/Vbox) on a Win11 with NVMe, and I use it every day for 5 years, have there been glitches, incompatibilities, or other problems with this type of setup?

I know that in theory on paper all of this should work fine. I know the VM has fake hardware, and it talks to the Hyper-V, which talks to the host hardware, etc. I am asking is there a technician who is aware of, or experienced glitches, incompatibilities, or problems with combinations similar to this? The application I am using this for must be perfectly reliable, that is the most important thing, I need the 5 Nines Baby. I don't really need the power or speed of a new PC, but it would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: It is not *technically* [supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/supported-guest-os) but it should work 100%.  Lots of people are doing it.  I myself *would* try it for you but my xp images are all VirtualBox and I don't have the time.  Gen2 won't work but that isn't a problem for you ;^)  If I were you, I would find a friend with Windows 11 and TRY IT.

Comment: Most modern processors will prevent Windows 7 from being able to update, this has been the case for a number of years (more than 3), any supported processor will have next to zero support for Windows XP and Windows 7 at this point.  While you are asking about a virtual machine you must consider processor support all the same.

Comment: That is the first time someone has told me that modern processors will prevent a normal physical host Win7 PC from updating the Windows system. Could you please link me to an article that says that?

On the question of WinXPx32 as a guest VM inside of Hyper-V, I do see on the list you sent me that WinXPx32 is not officially supported. I appreciate the idea of testing it, however my question is not about merely testing it, I have already done that. I have a mission critical task, where I need a WinXPx32 VHD Gen 1 guest VM image to work 100% reliable for years. How should I do that?